# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_rest_passwordreset'

Tags: html, django, backend, admin

I have tried to Create a Django Superuser Account for my Project by using: 'python manage.py createsuperuser' on the command Prompt error occurred - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_rest_passwordreset'

Comment: DRF should have nothing to do with that command. This looks to be related to another package - https://pypi.org/project/django-rest-passwordreset/. Have you added that to your `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: @michjnich  - The Resource that you have provided is So much helpful. Thank you So much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Python `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module_name'` occurs when we forget to install that module before importing it or installing it in an incorrect environment. To solve the error, install the module by running the `pip install module_name` command

In this scenario, the module is named as `django-rest-passwordreset`.

You can install that by running that command.

```
pip install django-rest-passwordreset
```

You can visit the [docs](https://pypi.org/project/django-rest-passwordreset/) for further details about that module.